# Are mission tokens considered Figures for sake of hero abilities?

Tags: star-wars-imperial-assault

One Hero has ability *Covert* that says *"**Hostile figures** 4 or more spaces away from you do not have line of sight to you. You do not block line of sight for those figures."* Side mission *Indebted* has Pulse Cannons marked by Imperial Mission Tokens. At the end of activation phase they shoot a Rebel in their lane of sight. It's not an attack, as they damage without giving any opportunity to defend and there's no range requirement. At one moment there was dispute if it can damage given hero, as it had unobstructed line of sight.

Rules Reference Guide defines Hostale Figure as follows: "*All figures belonging to a player’s opponent are considered hostile.*" Unfortunately, the guide doesn't define *figure* per se.

My (Imperial player) opinion was it would damage it, as this ability was talking about figures, and the Cannon was not figure. It doesn't obstruct movement or LoS, you can end your move on tile with it's token.

Unfortunately given situation was critical for Rebels, it was win or lose. As I had four players yelling at me it's not allowed, including game owner, I could only accept their interpretation or leave table. I'm looking for citations or other examples of abilities that would work the way I am expecting it to do. (Or citations confirming they're right)

Comment: Based on the use of the term `for figures`, I would agree with you on this interpretation. I can't find the official rules regarding invisibility though, so I can't confirm technically just yet. Which hero has this ability—first I've heard of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Mission tokens are not considered figures unless explicitly declared to be by the mission rules. Therefore, the Covert ability would not apply to Pulse Cannons.

From page 20 of the [Rules Reference Guide](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/ef/86/ef866943-534b-429e-b8db-7d99875431b7/imperial_assault_rules_reference_guide.pdf):

> #### Objects
>
> Objects refer to elements on the map that *are not figures*. Doors, crates, and terminals are all considered to be objects.
>
> - **Most mission tokens are considered to be objects**, unless the mission rules use the token to represent a figure.

The [Covert ability](http://cards.boardwars.eu/Core-Box/Rebel%20Heroes/Mak%20Eshka%27rey/Mak+Hero+Healthy.jpg) reads:

> #### Covert
>
> ***Hostile figures*** 4 or more spaces away from you do not have line of sight to you. You do not block line of sight for those ***figures***.

Since Pulse Cannons are represented by Imperial Mission Tokens, and are not explicitly referred to as figures in the Mission Rules, then they are not figures and Covert does not apply to them.